# Can partials access locals in sails? why not?

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js

I have an `index.ejs` for my homepage that renders `<%- partial ('../user/new.ejs') %>` for my signup page. In the process of adding flash error messages I noticed that the partial does not have access to locals *[flash undefined error]*. Meanwhile if I load the partial as a view (by accessing `root/user/new` directly then the flash messages are executed properly.

Could someone explain why this is, and is there any work around?

Potential cause: `index.ejs` is loaded via `res.redirect` meanwhile the dedicated signup view is loaded via `res.view`?

Controller:

```
create: function (req, res, next) {

    User.create({
        email: req.param('email'),
        encryptedPassword: req.param('password')
    }, function userCreated(err, user) {
        if (err) { 
            console.log(err); 

            req.session.flash = {
                err: err.ValidationError
            }

            return res.redirect('/');
        }
        res.redirect('/user/show/'+ user.id);
        //res.json(user);
    });
},
```

index.ejs is just `<%- partial ('../user/_signup.ejs') %>` for now

_signup.ejs

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="max-width:400px;">
<h1>Sign up</h1>
<form action="/user/create" method="post" role="form" class="form-signin">


<% if(flash && flash.err) { %>
    <ul class="alert alert-success">
    <% Object.keys(flash.err).forEach(function(err) { %>
        <li> <%- JSON.stringify(flash.err[err]) %></li>
    <% }) %>
    </ul>
<% } %>

    <div class="form-group control-group"> 
        <label for="email"></label>
        <input name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" type="text"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group control-group"> 
        <label for="password"></label>
        <input name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password" type="password" title="Password"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group control-group"> 
        <label for="passwordConfirmation"></label>
        <input name="passwordConfirmation" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" title="Password"/>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Signup" class="btn btn-success"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %>"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

The partial should definitely have access to any locals that you send down when rendering the view, so it seems like something else might be going on here.  Regardless, you can pass vars manually to the partial by sending them in as the second argument:

```
<%- partial ('../user/new.ejs', {flash: flash}) %>
```

Comment: This didn't work, I still get `flash undefined` from the `index.ejs`. My next guess is that the locals are not being fully passed from the `userController`. Could it be because I `redirect` to root after assigning `req.session.flash` instead of using `res.view`?